# Python, Type error, object instead of float after StandardScaler transform

Tags: python, scikit-learn, typeerror

My code is

```
a, b = train_df1.iloc[:,1:7].values, train_df1.iloc[:,0].values
c = test_df1.iloc[:,0:6].values

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
std = StandardScaler()
a_t= std.fit_transform(a)
c_t = std.transform(c)
```

I have two dataframes train_df1 and test_df1.

I created a, b, c using those.

Here the problem is a and b turned out to be float64 and int64 type respectively.

But c is object type which why it is showing type error for the next code.

How do I change c to float type so that to avoid type error for the subsequent code?

error message is

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'method'

It comes after running last line of code.

edit

```
train_df1.head(3)
```

Out[64]:

```
   Survived  Pclass  Sex   Age  SibSp  Parch     Fare  Embarked
0         0       3    0  22.0      1      0   7.2500         0
1         1       1    1  38.0      1      0  71.2833         1
2         1       3    1  26.0      0      0   7.9250         0

test_df1.head(3)
```

Out[65]:

```
   Pclass  Sex   Age  SibSp  Parch    Fare  Embarked
0       3    0  34.5      0      0  7.8292         2
1       3    1  47.0      1      0       7         0
2       2    0  62.0      0      0  9.6875         2
```

Comment: `c = test_df1.iloc[:,0:6].values.astype(np.float64)`?

Comment: I tried with c = float(test_df1.iloc[:,0:6}.values). but of no progress

Comment: Have you pre processed categorical data?

Comment: i tried what you suggested roganjosh. but the same erroris poppingup.

Comment: what is mean my pre processing categorical data? nagasivam

Comment: You need to use `@` before our names to send notifications. Also, please edit the error message into the question.

Comment: @SyamJalla Before using your data you need to convert a categorical  data into numerical values, For example if a column contains Yes and No here Yes is a category and No is a category you may convert Yes into 0 and no to 1. Remember, scikit learn has a method to do this.

Comment: @  Visweswaran Nagasivam i do converted categorical data.

Comment: It may also arise due to missing data. Can you show me the error message?

Comment: @ Visweswaran Nagasivam i added the error message

Comment: Voting to close this as its is not clear. Please post all the code by which you have made a,b , c. Preferably with some data samples.

Comment: @ Vivek Kumar its a very huge fairly large data frame train data frame has 850 observations and test data frame has 470 observations. I am adding first three observations of two data frames.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have shown a very little code I can't slap the code in my ide and debug it.
So, I have used a single data frame from your question and scaled the data

here is our data frame:

```
Survived  Pclass  Sex   Age  SibSp  Parch     Fare  Embarked
0         0       3    0  22.0      1      0   7.2500         0
1         1       1    1  38.0      1      0  71.2833         1
2         1       3    1  26.0      0      0   7.9250         0
```

Here is the code(with comments for your reference):

```
# SWAMI KARUPPASWAMI THUNNAI

import pandas
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data_set = pandas.read_csv("data.csv")
    a = data_set.iloc[:,1:7].values # a will get the values of 1st six columns
    b = data_set.iloc[:,7].values  # b will get the values of 7th columns
    # since the data set seems to be preprocessed (considering the small amount of data)
    # we will create training set and testing set
    a_train, a_test, b_train, b_test = train_test_split(a, b, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)
    # test data size = 20 % and pseudo random generator is set to 0
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    # now we are about to scale the data
    a_train = scaler.fit_transform(a_train) # scale the training set
    # use the mean and standard deviation of training set to scale the testing set
    a_test = scaler.transform(a_test)
```

So, finally I have scaled the values

[image]

Note: considering the little information and code I have assumed various things however I hope this will help you to solve your problem.